# Postgresql function dynamic table quote_ident error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a dynamic function. I get a part of table name with dynamically. The function is created successfully. But when I execute the function. I get an error. How can I solve this problem? I call the function with

```
select * from dwgcould.getlatlngcenter(2000653);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwgcould.getlatlngcenter(IN pro_id integer,
    OUT lat_center double precision, OUT lng_center double precision)
AS $$

BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'SELECT st_x(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lng_center  ,st_y(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lat_center
        FROM dwgcould.adpes_v1_' || quote_ident(pro_id) || '_line limit 1';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error code is

> ERROR:  function quote_ident(integer) does not exist
>   LINE 2:    FROM dwgcould.adpes_v1_' || quote_ident(pro_id) || '_line...
>                                          ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   QUERY:  SELECT 'SELECT st_x(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lng_center  ,st_y(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lat_center
>               FROM dwgcould.adpes_v1_' || quote_ident(pro_id) || '_line limit 1'
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.getlatlngcenter(integer) line 4 at EXECUTE statement
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: function quote_ident(integer) does not exist
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.getlatlngcenter(integer) line 4 at EXECUTE statement

Also How can I check whether table exist?

Comment: `if (select count(1) from pg_tables where tablename = 'tn') < 1 then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better use format, eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwgcould.getlatlngcenter(IN pro_id integer,
    OUT lat_center double precision, OUT lng_center double precision)
AS $$

BEGIN
  if (select count(1) from pg_tables where tablename = format('adpes_v1_%s_line',pro_id)) < 1 then
    raise info '%','NO SUCH TABLE!';
    return;
  end if;
  EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM dwgcould.adpes_v1_%s_line limit 1',pro_id) into lat_center,lng_center;
  return;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: İt is working but I get empty value. İf I execute directly SELECT st_x(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lng_center  ,st_y(st_centroid( st_transform(geom,4326))) as lat_center
  FROM dwgcould.adpes_v1_2000653_line limit 1 I get result.

Comment: add ` into lat_center,lng_center;` after execute